# No backlight on Late 2007 MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, display, backlight

I have an old Late 2007 MacBook, it has been working until few days ago. Suddenly the backlighting of the display stopped working.

Basically I turn on the computer and the screen is almost dark.

If I point a lamp in front of the display, I can see the interface behind, however even at maximum brightness it's still dark.

I've contacted Apple support but they told me that there are no replacements of a machine that old.

I'm quite comfortable at opening it and try to fix by myself but I don't know what parts i need. What could be the issue?

Comment: Sorry, just edited

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about only the backlight, but it is possible to replace the entire display assembly. With this computer, it is however a very difficult replacement. [Read this guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Core+Duo+Display+Replacement/304) and follow it carefully, being sure to allot several hours for the replacement.

With that said, given the age of this MacBook, it may not be worth fixing it up depending how much it costs.

Comment: So, do you think i need to replace the whole display?

Comment: @Matteo To be honest, I'm not sure. It might be possible to disassemble the display assembly and then replace just the backlight, but I didn't find any instructions for it, so I'm honestly not sure.